# How to update an SQLlite database periodically through the internet ?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an android application that needs to update periodically an SQLlite database of strings. Can updation be done through the internet, if yes how ?

I have a few lists in my application which are filled by the SQLlite database. The contents of the lists needs to change every day. That's why I need to update it everyday.

Comment: can you please elaborate your use-case

Comment: In My opinion this not possible,IF you have to update record and database,Then you have to used webservices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take following approach:

> > maintain a date variable in the shared preference or sqlite and on application launch check that if todays date is greater than date stored then you can call the rest/soap based web-services and fetch the updated record from server and update your sqlite table.In turn your list will populate the latest data...use cursorAdapter for that

```
                   OR
```

> > you can implement a GCM(google cloud messaging) service on your server,which push the       updated data from sever to client every day.

```
                 OR
```

> > every time you launc an application you can hit the web service and upadte your sqlite database.

I hope solution caters to your problem

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can update your Sql Database from the internet. See [Guide to Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).
You can fire an `Intent Service` which does the work on a separate thread and there you can make a connection (for example `HTTP GET` request) and then put the parsed data in your appropriate database.
If you are using `Loaders` to populate your list, the list will be updated when you store new data in your database.